# how to keep track of 3 input strings using 1 UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios

How can i keep track of 3 input strings from using 1 `UITextField`?

I am toggling between 3 different input types (departures, airlines, arrivals) using one UITextField for user input.  I save each of the 3 in its own `NSMutableString` object like this(depending on what's being entered or whatever):

```
depart = [input.text copy];
arrive = [input.text copy];
airline = [input.text copy];
```

i set the value of the UITextField(depending on what user is entering) using

```
input.text = [arrive copy];
input.text = [depart copy];
input.text = [airline copy];
```

i am successfully keeping track of each of the 3 inputs using `input.text copy` yet i am seeing memory leaking issues while running an `Instruments` test for leaks.  i have a feeling it is a result of my improper cleanup of using `copy`.  how can i retain each input string and not cause memory leaking issues?

Comment: using the method copy creates a new object instead of just keeping the existing value.  input.text = [airline copy]; is fine, because the value of .text is accessed through the property and the previous value is released.  airline = [input.text copy]; will cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your strings into properties that are retained.

```
@property (retain) NSString *airline;
```

Set the value of the properties using self.

```
self.airline = input.text;
```

Without using self, you're manually setting the value and bypassing the property, so the text is not retained.

Release the objects in your -(void)dealloc method

Then, when you're editing specific information, you can use the properties to populate the textField

```
input.text = self.airline;
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: so instead of `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableString *airline;` it would be `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableString *airline;` ?

Comment: wait, you changed your question around, i'm not sure this is what you want

Comment: no, you you're on the right track without the copy thing.  wait for my new answer

Answer (score 1):

Leaks tool should tell you where the leak is.

Here is pretty obvious though.
You should release old data prior to assigning new.
Thus, all calls like

`depart = [input.text copy];`

Should be like

`[depart release];
depart = [input.text copy];`

Also you should `release` all strings in the `dealloc` method of the class.

Comment: the leaks tool says the leak is in the Foundations library, which is highly not probable

Comment: Agree, Leaks are not always precise. Valgrind is better though it works only for simulator.